# Building an R package with a pre-compiled shared library

Tags: r, dll, package, shared-libraries

I am facing a problem with an R package that I am writing and trying to build with a pre-compiled shared library. Let me try to briefly describe the problem:

- this package (let's call it `mypack`) relies on a shared library `mylib.dll` that is already compiled and that I cannot compile on the fly while building the R package.
- the library `mylib.dll` has been compiled on a x64 machine under Windows and can be loaded in R with `dyn.load`.
- the package contains the required file `NAMESPACE`, where `useDynLib(mylib.dll)` is specified. The function `.onLoad` containing the instruction `library.dynam('mylib.dll', pkg, lib)` is also specified in a file `zzz.R`.
- the R package `mypack` is built with `Rtools` using the usual command `Rcmd INSTALL`, and I then add a directory `libs` where I save `mylib.dll`.
- when I try to load the package in R with `library(mypack)`, I get the following error message:
  `Error: package 'mypack' is not installed for 'arch=x64'`

This is puzzling me. Why can the shared library be loaded smoothly in R, but when I build a package using it I am getting this weird error message?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6):

That error message comes from this code in `library`:

```
 if (nzchar(r_arch) && file.exists(file.path(pkgpath, 
            "libs")) && !file.exists(file.path(pkgpath, "libs", 
            r_arch))) 
            stop(gettextf("package %s is not installed for 'arch=%s'", 
                sQuote(pkgname), r_arch), call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

which is telling me you need a {package}/libs/{arch} folder in your built package (ie the installed directory) with an {arch} that matches your system's arch, as given by  `r_arch <- .Platform$r_arch`

I'm guessing your build has failed to make this correctly. Is there any C code in your source?